# Audio File Streaming in Android not working one android 2.3

Tags: android, audio, streaming, media-player

I am working on audio streaming on android for soundcloud audio using media player , it is working on android 4.x and above devices but not working less than 4.0 like 2.3.3 and 2.2

Any other solution for streaming in android ?

stream url for sound cloud:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/81302334/stream?client_id=API_KEY_FOR_SOUNDCLOUD

Comment: The problem in the `https` which seems to not be supported in earlier `MediaPlayer`

Comment: I am also thinking like you, but what other option to stream audio using https?

Comment: This question has been asked here before with no answer. You might want to search for it again maybe someone found a solution and did answer that question.

Comment: Heay ,now am using HTTP histed of HTTPS and it's wokring

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem you might want to add it as an answer an accept it, so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media player in android <4.x supports only HTTP and 4.x n above support for BOTH http and https , so while using https with older API level, please think over it use http instead of https.